# perturbing discrete probability distribution

Tags: probability, discrete-data

What is the best way to slightly perturb a given discrete probability distribution ?

Adding a zero mean Gaussian noise to the probability distribution and re-normalizing it such that it sums to 1 is one way. But it does not ensure that all the probabilities are positive. Is there an other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "perturb"? Do you want to change the probabilities or the values (or both)? What is the purpose of this perturbation?

Comment: If you provided some motivation we could probably provide better advice.

Comment: I have to echo the other commenters - what is it you want to achieve? Also, do you want to end up with something continuous? discrete? mixed? you don't care?

Comment: The resulting probability distribution should be discrete and only the probabilities should change slightly compared to the original  probabilities. The values of the random variable should not change.. Hope it's clearer now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look at this problem geometrically, think of the
distribution  $[p_1, p_2 ... p_N]$ as a point in $N$ dimensional
space $\vec{p}$.  Now, since all the probabilities are positive and sum to
one, actual probability distribution lie on a hyperplane that 
diagonally spans one "quadrant" in this space (you can probably visualize it in $3D$ with some thought).

Now, you can perturb it by making a randomly selected small displacement in this 
vector space $\delta \vec{p}$, and then projecting the pertubed point back down to the hyperplane $\sum p_i =1$.  The only subtlety would be handling the case where due to the pertubation you end up with $p_i+\delta p_i <0$, which I'd just
handle via $p_i' = \lvert p_i + \delta p_i \rvert$, i.e. reflective boundary conditions at $p_i=0$.

The specific distribution for $\delta p_i$ could really be anything, and if you do $M$ small steps via this logic you could get something that could be claimed 
(in a non-rigorous manner) as being like a Gaussian perturbation.

Comment: Thanks.. It was the boundary condition that I didn't know how to handle when it is negative..

Answer (score 4):

A natural choice is to use the [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). $Dir(a p_1, a p_2, \cdots)$ will have mean equal to $(p_1, p_2, \cdots)$ and the variance can be controlled via $a$, and the samples are necessarily distributions.

Comment: Thanks. This is an alternative way to an additive perturbation. In this solution there are no worries about negative values..